# How to present a simple alert message in java?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

Coming from .NET i am so used calling Alert() in desktop apps. However in this java desktop app, I just want to alert a message saying "thank you for using java" I have to go through this much suffering:

(using a JOptionPane)

Is there an easier way?

Comment: What exactly do you expect from "easier"? If it's the verbosity, why not just wrap it in some static utility method and hide it away, for example? By the way, the official tutorial is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html).

Answer (score 276):

I'll be the first to admit Java can be very verbose, but I don't think this is unreasonable:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "My Goodness, this is so concise");
```

If you statically import `javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog` using:

```
import static javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog;
```

This further reduces to

```
showMessageDialog(null, "This is even shorter");
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with verbosity. In fact, I consider that one of its strengths.

Comment: @mre I guess this is either a joke or you're misunderstanding "verbosity"?

Comment: @mre unless you need the typing practice to transition to a secretarial job, I don't see how verbosity is desirable.

Comment: @Dónal When some simple thing takes a whole page of code to get working, that really creates a whole lot of extra jobs for people! :)

Comment: Good answer. Anyway, I can only use the first one. The second version which is shorter doesn't work (Error on the import command: "The import cannot be resolved").

Comment: @Alids to use the second version, you need to add the following to your imports `import static javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog`

Comment: Well, one argument for verbosity could be gained from a counterexample - I've spent quite a few minutes trying to disentangle the meaning of a single compact line, before.  Being brief sometimes comes at the cost of readability.  Granted, verbosity doesn't automatically grant readability.

Answer (score 42):

Assuming you already have a JFrame to call this from:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "thank you for using java");
```

See [The Java Tutorials: How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)
See [the JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html)

Comment: The first argument can be `null` if you don't have a `JFrame` available.

Comment: Note (to whom it may concern): `JOptionPane` is in `javax.swing`

Answer (score 37):

If you don't like "verbosity" you can always wrap your code in a short method:

```
private void msgbox(String s){
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, s);
}
```

and the usage:

```
msgbox("don't touch that!");
```

Answer (score 28):

Even without importing swing, you can get the call in one, all be it long, string. Otherwise just use the swing import and simple call:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thank you for using Java", "Yay, java", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

Easy enough.

Answer (score 11):

Call "setWarningMsg()" Method and pass the text that you want to show.

```
exm:- setWarningMsg("thank you for using java");


public static void setWarningMsg(String text){
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
    JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane(text,JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    JDialog dialog = optionPane.createDialog("Warning!");
    dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    dialog.setVisible(true);
}
```

Or Just use

```
JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane("thank you for using java",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
JDialog dialog = optionPane.createDialog("Warning!");
dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true); // to show top of all other application
dialog.setVisible(true); // to visible the dialog
```

You can use JOptionPane. (WARNING_MESSAGE or INFORMATION_MESSAGE or ERROR_MESSAGE)

Answer (score 2):

Can use this code simply like javascript:

```
void alert(String str){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, str);
    }
```